# Elastci search: exact match on array field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a data structure which includes a array field like this

```
{
  "platforms": ["ps4", "xbox", "web"]
}
```

How would I return all documents that matched "web" in the platforms field?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `platforms` is of type `keyword` the following query will work:

```
{
  "query":{
    "term":{
      "platforms": "web"
    }
  }
}
```

If the field is text and is auto created by elastic then replace `platforms` in above query by `platforms.keyword`.